# Android Google sign in not working for release apk

Tags: android, android-studio, google-signin

I am trying to integrate Google Sign In with backend server authentication in my Android app and it works successfully for my debug apk (using documentation here: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating and https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth).

The issue is that when generating a release apk (with my custom keystore), the google sign in always returns RESULT_CANCELED code.

My problem is that I don't know how to link google sign in api with my release keystore.

I also tried integrating google services plugin (using docs here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#get-config and here https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin). So I created a Firebase test project to download a generated google-services.json file and use it in Android Studio build.gradle.

I am stuck here, and I don't know what could I do next. I would also like to know if there is a solution without using a Firebase project.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue after all. I had 2 keys that I was testing with in my keystore and I was trying with one or another. More, I deleted some of the Android heys I created while testing. So, the main problem was that because I am using server backend authentication, I used the clientId created as Web Application, but I also needed to create an Android clientId in my Google Project, even though I do not use it anywhere in my project (just needs to be created there with the SHA1 and package name of my app).